# differentiate between ajax requests using parameters passed to the handler

Tags: jquery, ajax, event-handling

I am using `$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(event, xhr, settings) {` to update results when using pagination buttons. However, the page has two ajax functions so I need to differentiate between the two requests.

The jQuery api suggests '[you can use the parameters passed to the handler](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/)'.  My question is, how do I do this? What methods are available for use with the passed in objects?

For example I was hoping to be able to do something similar to:

```
if(event.attr('id') == 'x'){do stuff}
else {do other stuff}
```

The first ajax request is fired using pagination buttons (dataTables), the second is from a $.load() call.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you have the settings object.... so use the `setting.url` to differentiate the request

Comment: Why don't you do this within the local success handler?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VyVFC/1/ - but use local success handler if possible

Comment: I don't have access to the success handler of the dataTables pagination call. Using setting.url works, but seems a bit 'loose'. If the URL happens to change then it will fail. The callback function of $.load() does not override the $.ajaxSuccess function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only place where I suggest you take this approach is you don't have access to the said jqXHR object. Otherwise always use the `done`/`fail` fallbacks provided by the ajax promise object.

In that case use the setting parameter and then you can look at the url or any other settings passed to the ajax call to differentiate the requests like

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function (event, xhr, settings) {
    console.log('success')
    if(settings.url=='/echo/json/'){
        console.log('do json')
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VyVFC/)

Comment: thanks Arun. Do you happen to know where I can find a list of available methods for these objects? setting.url seems to be the way to go, although I would prefer a more robust solution.

Comment: what ever options are available for jQuery.ajax() could be there in the setting object

Comment: and for the event object?